# Symfony4/doctrine migration issue

Tags: ios, database, doctrine, mamp, symfony4

I'm having an issue trying to do a migration using the command line: php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
First of all: 
- I'm using symfony 4 in a group project on github 
- I'm using a mac and MAMP while other peeps from my group are using PCs and xampp

I'm pretty new to symfony 4 and github so I wouldn't be surprised if the solution was obvious.
So I cloned the project and used the php bin/console doctrine:database:create command line to have my database up and running.
However, I got an error message and after searching quite a bit, can't understand where the issue comes from:

> MacBook-Pro-de-Jeremy:globetriber jeremystephens$ php bin/console
>   doctrine:database:create 2018-02-18T17:18:58+01:00 [error] Error
>   thrown while running command "doctrine:database:create". Message: "An
>   exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection
>   refused"
>
> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 108:
>                                                                                    An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection
>   refused
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 47:
>                                                   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 43:
>                                                   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Let me know if you need any other information, thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Googling `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused ` shows a ton of answers, did you try them?

Comment: Yes I did but most of them refer to older versions of symfony which don't seem to be handled in the same way, for instance they refer to a parameters.yml file which doesn't exist anymore on symfony 4

Comment: I suppose there's some replacement for `parameters.yml`, isn't it?

Comment: I haven't found the answer to this yet. I ran some modifications/tests to the .env and the doctrine.yaml files but nothing changed/worked

Comment: Ok, turns out with MAMP, the Mysql port is on 8889 so I modified the .env URL: DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:8889/globetriber and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you must make sure the configuration of databasa is right [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#installing-doctrine)

in your .env file :

## customize this line!

DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name"